# Creating a simple android app for receiving bluetooth strings?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an Arduino sketch that sends some string via Bluetooth module (I'm using HC-06) and everything works great, with PuTTY.

Now. I'm new to Android developing and can't seem to find any good tutorial or piece of code that would wait for data from Bluetooth and print it to a textbox. Some are either outdated or are only about connecting and disconnecting from Bluetooth and seem to differ one from another. Or either there are huge amount of code with barely information or only snippets without notes where they go or what they are supposed to do.